# voice chat or audio call using socket in java

Tags: java, sockets, voip

**Scenario 1:** Voice Chat between two user/client working well, If and only If, both of them use headphone.

**Scenario 2:** If any one of them don't use headphone, then voice chat is working but noise is increased gradually.

**How it work**

Client 1's microphone sound recorded and send to Client 2. But Client 1's speaker sound also recorded and send to Client 2. So, Client 2 hear his own sound and Client 1's sound repeatedly. And noise is increasing and increasing.

**Purpose**

I need to stop recording of speakers sound. How can I read/ record only microphone's input sound by filtering speaker's sound? Please help.

Here is my code:

```
public class Server {
ServerSocket MyService;
Socket clientSocket = null;
InputStream input;
TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
OutputStream out;
AudioFormat audioFormat;
SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;
byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];
static Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();

Server() throws LineUnavailableException {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.show();
    try {
        Mixer mixer_ = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[0]);
        audioFormat = getAudioFormat();
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
        sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
        sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat);
        sourceDataLine.start();
        MyService = new ServerSocket(500);
        clientSocket = MyService.accept();
        captureAudio();
        input = new BufferedInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        while (input.read(tempBuffer) != -1) {
            sourceDataLine.write(tempBuffer, 0, 10000);

        }

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

private AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
    float sampleRate = 8000.0F;
    int sampleSizeInBits = 8;
    int channels = 1;
    boolean signed = true;
    boolean bigEndian = false;
    return new AudioFormat(
            sampleRate,
            sampleSizeInBits,
            channels,
            signed,
            bigEndian);
}

public static void main(String s[]) throws LineUnavailableException {
    Server s2 = new Server();
}

private void captureAudio() {
    try {

        audioFormat = getAudioFormat();
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(
                TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);
        Mixer mixer = null;
        System.out.println("Available mixers:");
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < mixerInfo.length; cnt++) {
            mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[3]);
            if (mixer.isLineSupported(dataLineInfo)) {
                System.out.println(mixerInfo[cnt].getName());
                targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(dataLineInfo);
            }
        }
        targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
        targetDataLine.start();

        Thread captureThread = new CaptureThread();
        captureThread.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

class CaptureThread extends Thread {

    byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                int cnt = targetDataLine.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length);
                out.write(tempBuffer);
                out.flush();

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}}
```

And

```
public class Client {
boolean stopCapture = false;
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream;
AudioFormat audioFormat;
TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
AudioInputStream audioInputStream;
BufferedOutputStream out = null;
BufferedInputStream in = null;
Socket sock = null;
SourceDataLine sourceDataLine;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Client tx = new Client();
    tx.captureAudio();
}

private void captureAudio() {
    try {
        sock = new Socket("192.168.1.3", 500);
        out = new BufferedOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
        in = new BufferedInputStream(sock.getInputStream());

        Mixer.Info[] mixerInfo = AudioSystem.getMixerInfo();
        System.out.println("Available mixers:");
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < mixerInfo.length; cnt++) {
            System.out.println(mixerInfo[cnt].getName());
        }
        audioFormat = getAudioFormat();

        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(
                TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);

        Mixer mixer = AudioSystem.getMixer(mixerInfo[2]);

        targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) mixer.getLine(dataLineInfo);

        targetDataLine.open(audioFormat);
        targetDataLine.start();

        Thread captureThread = new CaptureThread();
        captureThread.start();

        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo1 = new DataLine.Info(
                SourceDataLine.class, audioFormat);
        sourceDataLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem
                .getLine(dataLineInfo1);
        sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat);
        sourceDataLine.start();

        Thread playThread = new PlayThread();
        playThread.start();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

class CaptureThread extends Thread {

    byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];

    @Override
    public void run() {
        byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        stopCapture = false;
        try {
            while (!stopCapture) {

                int cnt = targetDataLine.read(tempBuffer, 0,
                        tempBuffer.length);

                out.write(tempBuffer);

                if (cnt > 0) {

                    byteArrayOutputStream.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);

                }
            }
            byteArrayOutputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

private AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
    float sampleRate = 8000.0F;

    int sampleSizeInBits = 8;

    int channels = 1;

    boolean signed = true;

    boolean bigEndian = false;

    return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleSizeInBits, channels, signed,
            bigEndian);
}

class PlayThread extends Thread {

    byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (in.read(tempBuffer) != -1) {
                sourceDataLine.write(tempBuffer, 0, 10000);

            }
            sourceDataLine.drain();
            sourceDataLine.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: So you're getting some feedback?

Comment: If it is feedback there is nothing you can do as a programmer. It is a technological issue.

Comment: Is there another way to create audio chat project using socket in java? Any suggestion please

Comment: Turn the knob back from '11' :)

Answer (score 2):

Typical "echo cancellation" issue when dealing with hands-free audio.

Try searching for a library who takes care of that because if you want to do it from scratch it is not trivial, matlab, adaptive filters, etc etc.

Sebas

Comment: I searched in google but did not get any library which hands-free audio.

Comment: DirectSound (windows) has a filter for it, 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a noise gate.
So if the users volume doesn't reach a certain value, the volume is set to 0